# Output the addition/subtraction/multiplication/division of two variables in a string?

Tags: javascript, variables

I need to output for example "variable + variable" without just displaying the end result. This is probably extremely simple (hopefully), but I'm having trouble with this.

```
  var rand1=Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
  var rand2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
  var result= rand1+rand2;
  document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML = result;
```

This obviously just returns the result of the two numbers added up. I need a way for this to output in the element like: Random Number + Random Number = Answer.

Comment: var result = rand1 + '' + rand2;

Comment: "" + rand1 + " + " + rand2 + " = " result

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. All were helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `innerHTML`'s value can be expressed as `rand1 + "+" + rand2 + "=" + result` as shown below,

```
  var rand1=Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
  var rand2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
  var result= rand1+rand2;
  document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML = rand1 + "+" + rand2 + "=" + result;
```

Answer (score 1):

THis would always works

```
var result= rand1.toString() + ' + ' + rand2.toString();
```

This should work too

```
var result= rand1 + ' + ' + rand2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You add the two random numbers and then you convert it to a String:

```
var sumrand = rand1+rand2;
var result = String(rand2) + '+' + String(rand2) + '=' + sumrand;
```